# How to conditionally scale a components Title element size when passed text is too long in VueJS? (using Sass and Flexbox)

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, flexbox, font-size

TLDR; What conditional variable should I be checking and what property should I be changing to have the title element react naturally when the word count is too high to fit the alloted space?
And what is the best practice for implimenting this conditional change in VueJS? (v-if?)

I'm looking for some guidance in figuring out what I have to do with the sizing of a title element I have for an app I am working on. I currently have the title displaying as an H1 element in between a hamburger menu and search icon (as seen in the first picture below).

[image]

However, when you got to the next view, where it would display the new title, it's too long to fit the given space and blows up the whole header section.

[image]

I am working in VueJS and I'm just not sure what I should do about this situation. I know I should have some sort of variable case that changes the class that decides it's font-size, but what is the variable I should be checking? Should I be checking with a v-if and then changing just the font-size?

MyHeader.vue (shownList is the only prop in this component)

```
<template>
  <div class="my-header">
    <div class="my-header_top-els">
      <img src="/svgs/menu.svg" />
      <div class="my-header_top-els_title">
        {{ shownList }}
      </div>
      <img src="/svgs/search.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="my-header_bottom-els">
     <div class="my-header_bottom-els_back-btn-included">
      <div class="back-title">
        <img src="/svgs/arrow-left.svg" class="back-icon" />
        <div class="t-nav-switch my-header_bottom-els_title">Back</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sort-title">
        <div class="t-nav-switch my-header_bottom-els_title">Sort Items</div>
        <img src="/svgs/sort.svg"class="icon" />
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Style

```
<style lang="sass" scoped>
.my-header
  position: fixed
  top: 0
  left: 0
  right: 0
  height: 9.25rem
  z-index: 1
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  justify-content: center
  border: none
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem
  background-color: #fffdf9
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)

  &_top-els
    display: flex
    margin-top: 1rem
    margin-bottom: 1rem
    padding-left: 1.75rem
    padding-right: 1.75rem
    &_title
      margin: 0rem auto
      color: sienna
      text-transform: capitalize
      font-weight: 500
      font-size: 3rem

.my-header_bottom-els
  display: flex
  flex-direction: row
  justify-content: center
  align-items: center
  margin: 0
  padding: 0
  &_line
    margin-left: 1rem
    margin-right: 1rem
    font-weight: bold
    color: sienna

.my-header_bottom-els_back-btn-included
  display: flex
  justify-content: space-around
  align-items: center

.location-title,
.category-title,
.sort-title,
.back-title
  display: flex
  margin: 0
  padding: 0
  color: blue
.sort-title
  color: avacado
.category-title
  color: gold
.icon
  margin-left: 0.5rem

.back-title
  color: sienna
.back-icon
  margin-right: 0.25rem

</style>
```

Comment: From what i am reading it's not really clear what you want to achieve when there is too much text. Do you want to make the text actually smaller or do you want to elisps it like
```
Box wi...
```

Comment: Hey there, thank you for the response and sorry about the delay.
I'm not sure what is the best option here. I was thinking intially that I wanted to make the font smaller, but I had never considered your elispses idea. That said however, I want the title legible so I tihnk resizing the font is the best option. I'm just not sure how I can do that. 

I was more or less looking for guidance about how to go about handling a situation like this and what is best overall for the user to see. 

Cheers!

Comment: lowering the font-size wont always be a good solution. In your case when you add the whole text, it could render too small based on logic that you would implement. My advice would be: If its a title then limit it to a certain amount of characters. And if possible prevent it from adding it inbetween the header. that way you have more time to spend on actual progress instead of an issue that is non-existant